# How to make a manual relationship relationship without using fluentapi

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't like to use the fluent api in an entity framework, instead, I  would prefer to use a manual way such as the following:

```
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }
```

but, how can I make a foreign key using this manual way above?

Comment: Why not use the database first approach? I almost always design my database first and then update my models from the database.

Comment: now i learn about EF i don't wanna get in touch with database
can you give me solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[ForeignKey("[Name of column]")]** anntribute. For examle:

```
public class Student
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int StandardRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StandardRefId")]
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

For more information see for examle [EF Code Firs Foreign keys](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s02.html)